# SQL for Selecting Current Month in a Date Field and then only if Current date in greater that a certain date

Tags: mysql, sql

This sql with mysql db does not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM `house1_rent_2014` 
WHERE MONTH( `FIRST_OF_MONTH` ) = MONTH( NOW() )
AND DATE_ADD(MONTH(`FIRST_OF_MONTH`,INTERVAL 15 DAY) <= CURDATE();
```

what I want to do is get all the current month vales from the column FIRST_OF_MONTH (that works OK by itself) and then add the additional test if  it's a current month value of course  in the date field and today's date is greater than the 15th of the current month then select that. In other words a field has 2014-09-01 (again, I only want date fields with the current month) if today is 9/15 or later then select it.

I'm getting mixed up w/syntax and perhaps proper logic. Grateful for help

Comment: Just from a quick glance, you're missing a closing `)` in the last line.

Comment: Other than that the explanation of what you want is too convoluted.  Clean up your question a bit and make it more clear what you want.

Comment: Providing sample data and expected output always help to show clearly what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you have is way more convoluted than it needs to be, and I think the specification is overly confusing too.

**"get all the current month vales from the column FIRST_OF_MONTH"**

Did you want to return values from September of last year too? (The MONTH() function only returns the month value (1 thru 12), and doesn't include the year, which seems a bit odd.

To get rows for the "current month", we'd typically do something like this:

```
 WHERE t.first_of_month >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') 
   AND t.first_of_month <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Predicates on a "bare column" allow MySQL to make effective use of an index, in this case, a range scan of an index with leading column of first_of_month. If we wrap those columns in a function, then MySQL has to evaluate the function on every row on the table.

"then add the additional test **if it's a current month value** of course in the date field **and today's date is greater than the 15th of the current month** then select that."

You already have a predicate that checks for dates in the "current month", there's no need to repeat that.

This predicate will evaluate to TRUE if the current date is after the 15th, and will return FALSE if the current date is the 15th or earlier.

```
   AND DATE(NOW()) > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-15')
```

---

Examples

If we have these rows in the table:

```
row  first_of_month
---  --------------
  1  2014-09-30
  2  2014-10-02
  3  2014-10-14
  4  2014-10-16
  5  2014-10-31
  6  2014-11-01
```

If we run a query with these predicates:

```
 WHERE t.first_of_month >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') 
   AND t.first_of_month <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND DATE(NOW()) > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-15')
```

If `DATE(NOW())` returns `'2014-10-11'`, then the third predicate will evaluate to FALSE, and no rows will be returned.

If `DATE(NOW())` returns `'2014-10-16'`, then all of the rows with first_of_month in the current month are returned, that is, rows 2 thru 5 in the example data.

If `DATE(NOW())` returns `'2014-11-07'`, then third predicate is false, and no rows are returned.

If `DATE(NOW())` returns `'2014-09-25'`, the query will return row 1 in the example data.

Comment: I'm still "absorbing" your answer - I must thank you!